# Exception caught by rendering library issue

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I see only blank white Page with this error:
Exception caught by rendering library
RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView ListView:file

here is the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<Categories>(
          future: _futureCategories,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Categories> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final name = snapshot.data?.data;
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: name?.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Scaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(
                          title: Text(' ${name?[index].name}'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return NewsError(
                errorMessage: '${snapshot.hasError}',
              );
            }
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }),
    ));
  }
}
```

any help?

Comment: can you include your future `_futureCategories`

Comment: ```void initState() {
    _futureCategories = _categoryService.getAllCategories();
    super.initState();
  }
  }```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use two scaffolds inside each other. Especially more than one scaffold and not inside a listview. Just use the cards and list tiles, without scaffold and appbar.